# Authenticating users that inherit from the django user class or django.contrib.auth.models.User

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I sub-classed from the django `User` class to create my own personalized version of it. The `User` class I can talking about is `django.contrib.auth.models.User`.

This is what it looks like:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as Auth_User


class User(Auth_User):

    # User data
    Age = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
    middle_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)

    # Properties
    @property
    def full_name(self):

        return str(self.first_name + ' ' + (self.middle_name + ' ' if self.middle_name else '') + self.last_name)

    # Overridden functions
    def __unicode__(self):

        return self.full_name
```

Please not that this is a simplified version of the model, there is more data, that really is not relevant to this question.

Now, when I try to authenticate via conventional means, its fails:

```
def login(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, "User/login.html")

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        new_user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if new_user is not None:
            if new_user.is_active:
                login(request, new_user)
        else:
            print "User is not alive, he/she died! :("

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/users/')
```

The HTML is nothing special:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="/users/login" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="username">
            Username:
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
        </label>
        <label for="password">
            Password:
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

So, how do I authenticate a my `User` class that is subclassed from the django user class?

Comment: Have you tried to set [AUTH_USER_MODEL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#auth-user-model) setting?

Comment: @alecxe: No I have not yet. I am in the process though.

Comment: when you say it fails, does `authenticate` return a `None` ?

Comment: @karthikr Yesm it returns a none, even when the user is actually there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your model is in an app that's in your installed apps list, the Auth_USER_MODEL is set as @alecxe mentioned, and that you ran sync db.

If you ran sync db BEFORE you setup your new user model, you'll need to nuke the database and run it again now that your model is in place.  This could explain why everything seems to be working but it's not.. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model):

> Changing AUTH_USER_MODEL has a big effect on your database structure. It changes the tables that are available, and it will affect the construction of foreign keys and many-to-many relationships. If you intend to set AUTH_USER_MODEL, you should set it before creating any migrations or running manage.py migrate for the first time.
>
> Changing this setting after you have tables created is not supported by makemigrations and will result in you having to manually write a set of migrations to fix your schema.